# Regex - Match a HTML tag(and the content) with the same tag inside

Tags: java, html, css, regex

I have a string like this

```
<some other tags and things> <span style="color: #e23d39;"><strong><span style="color: #2873ee;">Some Text</span></strong></span> <some other tags and things>
```

I want to extract every span with style and then replace it with other tag. For example from that string.
I want to match

```
<span style="color: #e23d39;"><strong><span style="color: #2873ee;">Some Text</span></strong></span>
```

In the first match take the style color of the first span and replace it with

```
<font color="#e23d39"><strong><span style="color: #2873ee;">Some Text</span></strong></font>
```

Then matches again, and here is the final string that I want.

```
<font color="#e23d39"><strong><font color= "#2873ee">Some Text</font></strong></font>
```

I'm using a `.replaceAll` function with Java, so there's no problem in that.
But using the regex like:

```
/<span\s*?style="(.*?)">((?:.|\n)*?)<\/span>/g
```

In the first run it take:

```
<span style="color: #e23d39;"><strong><span style="color: #2873ee;">Some Text</span>
```

and left outside the other part:

```
</strong></span>
```

So what is the correct regex or how can I fix this?

Comment: Wherever you found the `(?:.|\n)*?` pattern, know that this is one of the worst patterns I have seen. And HTML must be parsed with the HTML parser.

Comment: Could you include what you want to get vs. what you're getting?

Comment: I found it whiles I was looking for matching with or without line breaks. g.e.
<span style="xx"> (line break here \n)
asdasd
</span>

Comment: HTML is not a regular language, and therefore it cannot be represented with regular expressions. The only sane solution is to use a real parser.